# Increment the date by 1 day by comparing the current time and given time

Tags: php, date

I want to increment the date by 1 day by comparing two times.

**This is my code:**

```
   <?php 
    if(date("h:i a") > $query2['endtime'])
    {
      $date = new DateTime($date);
      $date->modify('+1 day');
      echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
       echo '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="'.date("Y-m-d").'">';
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="'.date("Y-m-d").'">';
    }

    ?>
```

I want to compare the current time by the time given by the user. I have fetched the time given by the user like this `$query2['endtime']`. But, it is showing me the error.

Please check my code and help.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you have missed opening brace of the else part `else {` <-- check here

Comment: can you tell me what is the mistake in this code @jitendrapurohit.

Comment: What error do you see ?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'date' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'.In this line echo  "<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="echo date("Y-m-d"); ">";

Comment: Your quotes are mixed up. Look at the highlighting from the formatted code.

Comment: Can you help @Qirel.

Comment: You are mixing single and double-quotes, and you try to use `echo` when already inside an `echo`. You want something like `echo '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="'.date("Y-m-d").'">';` (look closely at the quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change quotes and add '.' to join strings

```
 echo  "<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="echo date("Y-m-d"); ">";
```

to:

```
 echo  '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="' . date("Y-m-d") . '">';
```

Comment: Look at the last string in your final example, still some syntax error there. `date("Y-m-d") . ">';` ->`date("Y-m-d") . '">';`

Comment: It will increment date by 1 according to the condition or not.@maciejolsz,@Qirel.

Comment: this solves problem with error you have provided:

    syntax error, unexpected 'date' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'.In this line echo "<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="echo date("Y-m-d"); ">";

could you give us an example of input data ?

for example if we will compare:
date("h:i a") < '1:45 am' will return true even if date('h:i a') returns e.g. "11:45 am", so I guess you can't compare strings :)

Comment: so what is the solution.

Comment: you can try to use DateTime object